# How to delete woo commerce order pragmatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to delete an order from database i was tried using bellow function but this is not working.can any body tell me how to delete an order from db using order id.

```
<?php wc_delete_order_item( absint( $order_id ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce Orders is custom post type, therefore you can use wordpress functions for performing any operation like,

```
wp_delete_post($order_id);
```